# Can i use File.Encrypt for this purpose?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application, its Name and Logo can changed directly from a TXT and a PNG file in the same directory.

I want to give the user the ability to change the Logo and Text File from another application that does the following :

`Takes the Logo.png , Name.txt file paths and the  directory of my Software then encrypt these two files and put them in the Directory of the Software`

In the other hand. The software will Decrypt these two files and write them to Hard Disk to temp directory then use them to display the name and the logo.

I searched for the simplest and easiest way to encrypt a file and i found :

From the MSDN :

File.Encrypt():
`Encrypts a file so that only the account used to encrypt the file can decrypt it.`

Could someone please tell me what does it mean "**only the account used to encrypt a file can decrypt it**"

What about encrypting the application from **Computer1** by **Application1** then the file will be decrypted by **Computer2** in **Application2**

Will the encryption work correctly ?

**Edit:**
The purpose why I need to encrypt these two files is to avoid users from directly change the Logo and the Name of Application from the directory

Comment: will application2 on computer2 be run by the same account as application1 on computer1?

Comment: No Application 2 run on a different computer

Comment: if the computers are on the same domain you needn't infer that.

Comment: The goal is pointless. Even if you actually encrypt the files, the key (or, equivalently, the way to get the key) will be somewhere the user can access it. And even without a key, the user could just go ahead and replace the files (the new ones will be decrypted into essentially random data, but they will still have been replaced).

Comment: @Jodrell - If they are on different machines then you can't use the machine encryption that File.Encrypt uses.

Comment: @Ramhound, is your assertion based on experience? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457116.aspx#EHAA

Comment: @Jodrell - Of course....Experience based on the documenation and the description of the method in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will encrypt the file, but not as you expect - and almost certainly not such that it can be decrypted by another application/user on a different computer.

The `Encrypt` method basically just toggles a feature of the underlying NTFS driver to encrypt the specified file on the file system itself. The nice feature is that it (typically) provides seamless file encryption for the user, but it isn't really portable encryption. It is the same as opening the file properties, clicking the advanced button and selecting the "Encrypt" checkbox.

More information on the encrypting feature of NTFS can be be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457116.aspx

[image: advanced file properties]

Answer (score 1):

No. You should use a proper encryption method such as those in System.Security.Cryptography namespace. There is a stream implementation for this, too, called CryptoStream, which you may wrap a FileStream with for encrypting files with.

Comment: where should the key be stored?

Comment: @Jodrell - Application's installation directory is a good place.

Comment: @Ramhound in that case you may as well store the clear files in the Application installation directory. Oh wait ...

Comment: @Jodrell - If you know the answer post your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to Windows' EFS.

You can try it from Windows Explorer by right-clicking on the file, Properties, Advanced, Encrypt contents. The file data is automatically decrypted/encrypted on the fly as your app accesses it. But if another user logs in the machine and copies the file it will appear encrypted since the encryption is based on a user token.

This is may or may not be what you want and that depends on your intended use of that feature. If you don't want the user to be able to modify the data outside your app it won't be enough.